# How to escape string in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to construct a script (php) where I copy certain DB-fields from my old DB to a new one.

Some fields contains special characters like ' and I can't get around that the script crashes when a post includes this. I have tried with:

mysql_real_escape_string($cat2ss['name']) 
and
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($cat2ss['name']))

but they both crashes.

Any ideas how to get around this?

This is a sample code:

```
$cat2s="SELECT * FROM o_product_description";
$cat2s_ex=mysql_query($cat2s) or die('<p>'.$cat2s.'</p>'.mysql_error());

while($cat2ss = mysql_fetch_array($cat2s_ex))
{
    $cat2sc = "INSERT INTO product_description (product_id, language_id, name, description, quality, catalog, cat_no, cat_val, cancellation, meta_description, meta_keyword, seo_keyword, catalogue, sort_order, attribut) VALUES ('".$cat2ss['product_id']."', '".$cat2ss['language_id']."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($cat2ss['name'])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($cat2ss['description'])."', '".$cat2ss['quality']."', '".$cat2ss['catalog']."', '".$cat2ss['cat_no']."', '".$cat2ss['cat_val']."', '".$cat2ss['cancellation']."', '".$cat2ss['meta_description']."', '".$cat2ss['meta_keyword']."', '".$cat2ss['seo_keyword']."', '".$cat2ss['catalogue']."', '".$cat2ss['sort_order']."', '".$cat2ss['attribut']."')";

    $cat2sc_ex=mysql_query($cat2sc) or die('<p>'.$cat2sc.'</p>'.mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: What happens when the script crashes? What kind of notice or error do you get?

Comment: Can you post more than this? An example query where you're having trouble would be much more insightful. In any case, those functions should not be used, they're being removed from PHP, and the best practice is to [spend a half hour to learn PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and use that instead.

Comment: The script runs until it hits a text string with a special character )like '). See the following error message:

Comment: ...VALUES ('10778', '2', '', '', 'vht', '', 'F.52', '0', 'lyckÃ¥sgÃ¥rd', '', 'F.52, 5 Ã¶re Oscar II, LYCKÃ…S'GÃ…RD 15-11-03 [F/SM] vht', 'f52-5-re-oscar-ii-lycksgrd-15-11-03-fsm-vht', '', '0', '')

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using PDO?  Without being able to give you exact code without knowing the line you want, you'd just do something like

```
$sql="SQL STATEMENT WITH :name"
$dbh->prepare($sql)
$dbh->execute(array(':name' => $cat2ss['name']));
```

Comment: What I want to do is to transfer certain data fields from my old DB to a new DB. I can manage to do the 'normal' transfer but when the script hits special characters in a VARCHAR field it stops/crashes.

Comment: Thats what PDO's prepare statement is great at.  It handles all the special character situations (as well as SQL injection, etc) so you don't have to worry about what the variables contain.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing the database connection id. Your code should be something like:

```
$db = mysql_connect();
$var = mysql_real_scape_string($db, $the_string_to_scape);
```

Of course, you must connect to the database with the correct parameters.